# I can't run a Java program

Tags: java

I was starting to learn Java. I followed the tutorial on how to install it.
I also checked by typing "javac"(without the quotation marks) in cmd if it works. And yes it gives a whole list of text which means its supposed to work, right?

This is my java code:

```
class apples{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.printIn("hello youtube");
    }
}
```

I saved it in a folder called 'test' in my c drive.
This is what I typed in cmd:

```
cd \
dir
```

*now it lists everything in my c drive and one of them is test*

```
cd test
dir
```

Now it lists everything in test and one of them is '`youtube.java`'(the file I named), so I type

```
javac youtube.java
```

This doesn't work
This is what it gives me:

> youtube.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
>   System.out.printIn("hello youtube");
>   symbol:  method printIn(string)
>   location: variable out of type PrintStream
>   1 error

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Well,  there's no such thing as `printIn` in Java, so I'd say that error is 100% accurate.

Comment: I think downvoting the question is a bit mean, we were all beginners once

Comment: @NickJ I agree The question contains good content and its clear what the question is.  I do not understand the downvotes

Comment: The real answer is that the OP should be starting with a good beginner's book on Java, or the Oracle tutorials.

Comment: I also didn't understand the downvoting, so I upvoted him

Comment: SO should introduce a mandatory comment section for downvotes

Comment: Did I piss people off? Thank you for putting up with me :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a typo in your call.  Change

```
System.out.printIn("hello youtube");  // capital 'I'
```

to

```
System.out.println("hello youtube");  // lowercase 'l'
```

And as has been mentioned already, in Java, the `public` class in a file must match the filename.

Comment: Some fonts make such characters appear identical.

Comment: @rgettman I wish SO would use [this ugly font](http://www.pgdp.net/c/faq/font_sample.php).

Answer (score 0):

The name of the class must match the filename.

You should use

```
public class Youtube{
```

in your code(as class names are capitalized) and call the file `Youtube.java`.

Also you used `In` instead of `ln`.

Use:

```
System.out.println(
```

which means "print line to System.out".

Comment: Well, you just saved us from a soon to come question. Not completely though. Class name should be `public`.