# Cannot find symbol cmd compiling error?

Tags: java, cmd

I created a folder called "test" in "C:". When i try to compile my "test.java" in "test" folder with the code:

```
class apples {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.printIn("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

i recieve this error:

```
C:\test>javac test.java
test.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
                System.out.printIn("Hello World!");
                          ^
  symbol:   method printIn(String)
  location: variable out of type PrintStream
1 error
```

What should i do? I checked the other questions but coulndt find the answer. (I know its a dupe, please help me and dont just tell dupe.)

Comment: `printIn` or `println`? Also, if your file is called `test.java`, you probably should have a class called `test` inside.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I can't run a Java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601492/i-cant-run-a-java-program)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo - it's `System.out.println` (lower case L, short for print line), not `System.out.printIn` (uppercase I)

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis He already answered. But thanks. :)