# System.out.printIn() error?

Tags: java

I'm super new to Java programming (and not good at this yet), I am just trying to compile this little program so I can use it doing an inheritance and polymorphism problem later. I'm using JGrasp and it keeps telling me that there is something about the System.out.printIn() that I am doing wrong. Do I need to import something? This is what I have:

```
public class Book   
{
private String title;

private int pages;
public Book(String title, int pages)
{
this.title = new String(title);
setPages(pages);
}
public void setPages(int pages)
{
this.pages = pages;    
}
public int getPages()
{
return pages;           //superclass method   
}
public void print()
{
System.out.printIn(title + " has " + pages + " pages");
}
}
```

The output I get is:

```
Book.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
  System.out.printIn(title + " has " + pages + " pages");

            ^

symbol:   method printIn(String)
location: variable out of type PrintStream
1 error
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `println` vs `printIn`. Voting to close for typographical error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I can't run a Java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601492/i-cant-run-a-java-program)

Comment: I think @SotiriosDelimanolis is right. Voting to close for typographical error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its just a typo.  The method is called `println` with a minor L, you wrote `printIn` with a major I.

Comment: Thank you, you have made this class easier to understand! I need reading glasses. Thank you.